# Экспорт данных php excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Всем привет,у меня есть отчет, в нём основные названия магазинов, а в каждом магазине еще свернутым списком продукты висят, косяк вот в чем, скрипт выводит все что есть и вложенные списки и основные названия на одном уровне, мне нужно что бы он выводил только названия магазинов, без списка продуктов, может кто сталкивался с таким, как это можно реализовать? использую библиотеку `PHPExcel`, заранее спасибо))

```
$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('otchet.xls');
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sheet->getHighestRow(); $i++)  {  
    echo "<tr><th>"; 
    $nColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());  

    for ($j = 0; $j < $nColumn; $j++)  {
        $value = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($j, $i)->getValue(); 
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
    }   echo "</th></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Если кратко, то просто не выводите продукты и всё. Если подробно, то давайте ваш скрипт, который формирует файл excel, без него ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно.

Comment: добавил к вопросу

Comment: А файлик можно показать, где магазины в нем лежат и где продукты?

Comment: к сожалению файлик дать не могу

Comment: хотя бы структуру его покажите, не обязательно с реальными данными

Comment: Да структура файла в вашем случае необходима для ответа на вопрос т.к. скрипт просто тупо перебирает все поля файла и выводит их на экран.
И, кстати, речь идёт об импорте, а не об экспорте.

Comment: Всем спасибо, с этим я разобрался, но возник следующий вопрос, массив я прочитал все шикарно, но в нескольких индексах появились значения #NULL!, какая причина этого??